# Independence of Gravitational acceleration with depth if local density of earth is 2/3 of average density

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets, density

> Show That the acceleration of gravity in a vertical mine shaft is independent of the depth if the local density of the Earth is 2/3 of the average density. Assume that the Earth is a spherically symmetric,non-rotating body.

This is a question from the book Resnick Halliday Krane vol 1 P14-10. The reference is "Gravity in a Mine Shaft" by Peter M.Hall and David J.Hall, The Physics Teacher, November 1995 p.525.)

I don't understand what it means by the term local density and what the question is asking. There's a pdf available of citation but I'm not able to download it https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.2344284?journalCode=pte

There's a similar question available but the solution is quite not clear that what actually is happening . Please before downvoting or marking this question as a duplicate, help me to understand this question. [Why is the gravity in a mine shaft independent of depth if the local density is 2/3 of the average density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/220693/)

Comment: Can you find the acceleration in a mine shaft if the density of the Earth were constant? Do you know what Gauss' law is? Grade 10 background is not the same over the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a spherically symmetric planet (think concentric shells of density that vary with radius), Gauss's Law say the gravity you feel at $r_0$ depends only on the mass at $r<r_0$.

So if you go down a 100m mine shaft, the gravity from the top 100m of the entire planet adds to zero.

Moreover, any mass, $M$, below you acts as if it were concentrated at the center, with force per unit mass:

$$ g = G\frac M {r_0^2} $$

So for a spherical Earth, the gravity at the surface is the same if all the mass is in a pea-sized  lump at the center, or a thin, dense, shell making a hollow planet.

That's the physics principle. The rest is implementation.

The gravity at the surface is:

$$ g(r) = G\frac M{r^2}$$

If we reduce $r$, there is less mass $M$ pulling on us, but it is closer, so it pulls harder. At which density do the two effects cancel?

From here you apply calculus's rule$^1$ for the derivative of a ratio:

$$ \frac{dg}{dr}=\frac{G}{r^2}\left(\frac{dM}{dr}-\frac{2M} r \right)=0$$

or:

$$\frac{dM}{dr} = \frac{2M} r $$

The LHS is the surface area times the local density:

$$\frac{dM}{dr} = 4\pi r^2\rho(r)$$

Meanwhile, on the RHS, the mass is the volume times the average density:

$$ M =\frac {4\pi} 3 r^3 \bar{\rho}$$

Combine those:

$$4\pi r^2\rho(r) = \frac {4\pi} 3 r^3 \bar{\rho}\frac 2 r$$

and voila:

$$\rho(r) =\frac 2 3 \bar{\rho}$$

A very nice problem.

[1] The quotient rule is the derivative$^2$ of the quotient of two functions:

$$ \left(\frac f g\right)'=\frac{gf'-fg'}{g^2}$$

Here I set:

$$ f(r)=M(r)\rightarrow f'=dM/dr$$
$$ g(r)=r^2 \rightarrow g'=2r $$

so

$$(f/g)'=\frac{(dM/dr)r^2 - 2Mr}{r^4}=\frac 1{r^2}\left(\frac{dM}{dr} -\frac{2M}r\right)$$

[2] The derivative is a formal way to quantify  how a function changes. The field that deals with this is called calculus.

Here, we are interest in the gravity at the Earth surface ($R$):

$$ g(R) = g(r)_{|_{r=R}}$$

and it's value at a slightly smaller $r=R-\delta r\ $, $g(R-\delta r)$. The change in the gravity strength is:

$$-\delta g = g(R-\delta r)-g(R)$$

To get the rate of change, we need to compute thechjnge in gravity per small distance shifted:

$$\frac{-\delta g}{\delta r} = \frac{g(R-\delta r)-g(R)}{\delta r}$$

In the limit that $\delta r\rightarrow 0$, this defines the derivative:

$$-\frac{dg}{dr}\equiv_{\delta r\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(R-\delta r)-g(R)}{\delta r}$$

(where the minus signs are because we're decreasing $r$ as required in the problem).

The good news as that many derivatives are well known, particularly any power functions:

$$ f(x) = x^n $$

The derivative, often written as "prime", is:

$$\frac{df}{dx}=f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$$

so with $n=-2$:

$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac 1 {x^2}\right)=\frac d{dx}(x^{-2})=-2x^{-3}=\frac{-2}{x^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the phrasing is super bad.

Rather than fight through the phrasing, might I suggest solving the problem in a different way:

Assume the density of the (spherical) earth is some function $\rho(r)$.

Go and use Gauss's law to find the acceleration due to gravity in a mine shaft.  Once you have an answer (that depends on $\rho(r)$), you can go and figure out what form $\rho(r)$ has to have so that the acceleration due to gravity doesn't depend on depth.  To satisfy the original question, go and relate this answer to the average density of the earth.

Once you know THAT, you'll have answered your question in reverse.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit , actually I'm in Grade 10 and am facing difficulty in relating Gauss's law from Electromagnetism to Gravity.

Comment: @Plank: there the trick is to realize that $\epsilon\oint {\vec E}\cdot d{\vec A} = q$ is really the same law as $E = k\frac{q}{r^{2}}$.  Once you see this, you can say, hey, $g = G\frac{m}{r^{2}}$ has to have a "Gauss's law form" that is just $\frac{1}{4\pi G}\oint {\vec g}\cdot d{\vec A} = M_{\rm inc}$.  And then, you can solve any "gauss's law setup" for gravity, by using this law, and subsituting "matter density" for "charge density"

Comment: and with the idea that the acceleration due to gravity is just the "gravitational field" the same way that the electric field is for electricity, since: $F = mg$ the same way that $F = qE$

Comment: I tried many times but I am still not able to solve.Please help me with detailed explanation.